# Need useEffect hook invoke when URL changes

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to have this component load data depending on its current url whether /global or /my-posts. The useEffect() grabs the data from the first loading of the component but when i change to another url i expected useEffect to check the url again and load the correct data but instead i'm stuck with the data from the first load. How do i get useEffect to invoke every time i click between different urls like /global and /my-posts url.

```
export default function Dashboard() {
  const [allRecipes, setAllRecipes] = useState([]);
  const [myRecipes, setMyRecipes] = useState([]);
  const currentUrl = window.location.pathname;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (currentUrl === '/dashboard/global') {
      console.log('hello');
      trackPromise(
        RecipeService.getAllRecipes()
          .then((data) => {
            setAllRecipes(data);
          }),
      );
    } else if (currentUrl === '/dashboard/my-posts') {
      console.log('hi');
      trackPromise(
        RecipeService.getRecipes()
          .then((data) => {
            setMyRecipes(data);
          }),
      );
    }
  }, []);
  console.log(window.location.pathname);
  return (
    <>
      <div className="dashboard">
        <DashboardHeader />
        <div className="created-posts">
          {allRecipes.length !== 0
            ? allRecipes.map((recipe) => <Post recipe={recipe} key={uuidv1()} />)
            : null}
          {myRecipes.length !== 0
            ? myRecipes.recipes.map((recipe) => <Post recipe={recipe} key={uuidv1()} />)
            : null}
          {currentUrl === '/dashboard/create' ? <CreateForm /> : null}
          <LoadingIndicator />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: pass currentUrl to useEffect dependency array => [currentUrl]

Comment: add `currentUrl` into your dep array of `useEffect`. Right now it doesn't pick up the changes cause you haven't provided it with the variable that you want to be observing.

Answer (score 1):

to make `React.useEffect` run on every `currentUrl` change, you have to add it to `useEffect` dependencies array.

```js
// first we need to control the state of window.location.pathname by react not the browser
// and make react state be the only source of truth.
const pathname = window.location.pathname

// manage currentUrl in state.
const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = React.useState(pathname)
React.useEffect(() => {
   setCurrentUrl(pathname)
}, [pathname])

// now you would add the contolled `currentUrl` state to its useEffect deps.
useEffect(() => {
  if (currentUrl === '/dashboard/global') {
    // ..........
  } else if (currentUrl === '/dashboard/my-posts') {
    // ..........
  }
}, [currentUrl]);
```

Answer (score -2):

This will detect url change

```
    useEffect(()=>{
    // your code to update the UI
    },[history.length])
```

Comment: where does history come from?